# Drop down question

Tags: php, plugin-development, css, html

I am new to wordpress. Please pardon this question as it may seem mundane. How do I make a drop down menu for Information to the end-user in wordpress?

similar to this...

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Where do you want to add the dropdown? Where will its data come from? Are you wanting to add it to the back end (wp-admin area) or on the front end of the site? What page, category, etc.? Is the data in some custom table or just regular CPTs and taxonomies? (As an aside, I hope that if you are dealing with social security numbers your site is extremely secure. You will likely be financially liable if any data breach occurs.)

Comment: all are  is flat text. example where is the office? office is in New York, NY I am not dealing with any ssn. I pulled that from the DOL website as an example only since that is what i want it to look like.

Comment: Ok, that's cool - but you still would need to identify where you want the dropdowns added (front end, back end, what page) and where the data will come from (do you want to type it into the Editor, is it coming from your database) so someone can answer.

Comment: I want it to be showed on the same page. I want to have it pulled from the front end (editor) preferably if that is possible. That is the ideal way. 


IF that is not possible How do I pull it from the database.

whichever is the easiest way.

Comment: I don't think we could answer your question about how to do this, simply because thats more of a discussion than a question as WebElaine has illustrated above. As for the example you share, that would normally be described as an 'Accordion' and the link below is just one framework that could help you output that. However, this isn't something specific to Wordpress development. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: The "same page" does not tell us where you are trying to put the dropdown, and the front end is not the Editor. It sounds like possibly you may just be looking for a way to create dropdowns in the Editor. If you are using the Block Editor, you can look for a plugin that provides a dropdown block. If you are using Classic Editor, you may need a shortcode, for which there may also be a plugin. But without a lot more detail your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Thank you  t2pe. That is exactly what I want !!! I just did not know the name of it, Accordion. The issue and problem is resolved!! How do I mark it as solved and give you credit ?!